# Value of a scala variable do not change while executing play Future query. Why?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am new to SCALA language and making an API service with play and slick.   Look at the following code.

```
def checkToken(userToken: String): Boolean = {
      var status = false
      Tokens.getToken(userToken).map(
          token => {
            if (token.isDefined && token.get.status.equals("ACTIVE")) {
                status = true
                println("--------------------------------- if: "+status+" -----------------------------")
            } else {
                status = false
                println("--------------------------------- else: "+status+" -----------------------------")
            }
          }
      )
      println("---------------------------------status: "+status+"-----------------------------")
      return status
    }
```

While executing the above code it shows the following output

```
---------------------------------status: false-----------------------------
--------------------------------- if: true -----------------------------
```

But the output should be [both should be true for a valid token]

```
---------------------------------status: true-----------------------------
--------------------------------- if: true -----------------------------
```

What is the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a timing issue.

If `getToken` returns a `Future`, when your "main" thread arrives on `Tokens.getToken(userToken)`, it will execute it on a different thread. In the meantime, the main thread keeps on moving, arrives at `print("status"+status)` before it actually had time to change, and the function returns. Only then does the `Future` returns at some point and, still on that separate thread, will execute the code inside `map` and change the value of `status`.

What I think you want is a function that returns a `Future[Boolean]` (edited to match @rethab suggestion):

```
def checkToken(userToken: String): Future[Boolean] = Tokens.getToken(userToken).map(_.contains("ACTIVE"))
```

Comment: Even easier: ```Tokens.getToken(userToken).map(_.contains("ACTIVE"))```

Comment: I think what it should be is `Tokens.getToken(userToken).map(_.exists(_.status == "ACTIVE"))`

Comment: not sure what you mean since `None.contains("ACTIVE")` will return `false` while `Some("ACTIVE").contains("ACTIVE")` will return `true`

Comment: Well I refer to the original question which contains following: `token.get.status.equals("ACTIVE")` which means `token` is an `Option[SomeTypeWithStringPropertyCalledStatus]`, not an `Option[String]`. Not sure how OP didn't notice that and accepted the answer.